# Authotkey, Conemu and pycmd

Tags: autohotkey, conemu

I'm using conemu, pycmd and autohotkey.

```
::/artask::
    Send, d:{ENTER}
    Send, cd \{ENTER}
    Send, cd projects{ENTER}
    Send, cd ar-drone{ENTER}
    Send, cd tasklist{ENTER}
Return
```

Typing `/artask` followed by return does sometime work but most time not.

I often get some output like

```
cd a-drone
cd taskist
...
```

It seems that single chars get lost. Testing it with "MS DOS" shell it
seems to work fine.

I prefer conemu and pycmd, so any idea how to work around?

Comment: Try different settings for `SetKeyDelay` and or `SendMode`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in ConEmu, more correct way to do what you want - [GuiMacro](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/GuiMacro)
Just execute following command instead of sending keys one one

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro:0 print "d:\ncd \\projects\\ar-drone\\tasklist\n"
```